# Getting 502 Bad Gateway Error with ExpressJS, Nginx & PM2

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, pm2

I am trying to host this [Github repository](https://github.com/anders94/blockchain-demo) on Ubuntu 16 with Nginx. But I am getting 502 bad request error. For deploying the express js app, I have followed this [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04). I have cloned the repo in home directory and installed pm2. I have also started my app using `pm2 start app.js` and it is working. Here is the my pm2 status:
[image]
[image]

I have also configured Nginx proxy server according to the mentioned Digital Ocean tutorial. My configuration file (Location: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default) is as below:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        #root /var/www/html;
        root /home/ubuntu/blockchain-demo/routes;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.js index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 54.255.173.175; #this is my public IP. I don't have domain.

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

The Nginx error log is as follows:

```
2018/10/15 15:38:13 [error] 6283#6283: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 27.147.204.239, server: 54.255.173.175, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "54.255.173.175"
2018/10/15 15:38:14 [error] 6283#6283: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 27.147.204.239, server:54.255.173.175, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "54.255.173.175", referrer:http://54.255.173.175/"
```

I have googled and found different solution. One of the solution suggested to check the localhost:3000 port. Here is my localhost port report:
[image]

Can anyone help me to figure out where is the problem that causes the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the root is `/home/ubuntu/blockchain-demo/routes;` and not `/home/ubuntu/blockchain-demo;`?

Comment: There is a index.js file in the routes folder. Hence, I poited to that folder. But after that, I have changed the root to home/ubuntu/blockchain-demo folder, where app.js file is located. But I am getting 502 error as earlier.

Comment: @MuminurRahman did u figured out?

Comment: Nope, I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

please try sudo pm2 start app.js